# What does the different terminal file colors mean in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I was using Linux terminal and I wondered why some files have different colors from others
do they only have colors to show the type and permissions given to the file?

Comment: Off-topic as it has nothing to do with programming; voted to close.  You may want to try [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: No that's not off topic I'm asking this to find out if its possible to change them using programming or not, because if they are fixed it will not be possible for me to change them, however if I could it would give me a good feature to put in my code. Hope you got my idea.

Comment: Ummm .. no. Just because I'm thinking about writing an algorithm for a self-driving car doesn't make a question about varied car parts a programming question.

Comment: so can you help me ask about the method I can use to change terminal file colors using programming I'm new here as you can tell and I don't really now the syntax I need to use to ask this specific question

Comment: Sure .. `man ls`, `/color`, where you'll find a reference to `man dircolors` ...  or go to the right place to ask if reading a man-page is too hard. The right place being [unix.se].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like that each color do have a meaning, take a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, I just tought it could be useful  to answer because he could not know these two other forums.

Comment: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is good too, if you are using Ubuntu.